# Django local flavor select widget list

Tags: django, postgresql, django-localflavor

My question is pretty siemple, but is being hard for me to find an easy way to do this.

I have a website where I need to make three dropdowns:

1. One for countrys
2. One for regions
3. One for sub-regions

My website has multiple languages. What I need to do is making a 'select widget' whose input is the current language, and drop down a list of the countries in that language. After selecting the country, a second select with subregions from that country and language. And so.

For example: 3 dropdowns. Spain - Balearic Island - Palma de Mallorca

I'm using Django 1.5 with a PostgreSql.

Can you help me out with this please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating for a while a decided just to make one drop down list with only countries. Regions and subregions are left as free text for users.

Making a multilingual dropdown for regions and subregions is quite hard, so many combinations. Some big developed project such as Prestashop do it in this way.

Hope this help someone ;)